# Javascript - Detect reverse pairs in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
[
{source: 'A', target : 'C', value: 25}, 
{source: 'E', target: 'F', value: 5}, 
{source: 'C', target: 'A', value: 20}, ...
]
```

How can I detect all reverse pairs such as source: 'A', target: 'C' and source: 'C', target: 'A' and make a sum of value: 25 + 20 ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sorted joint key for a pair with a hash table.

```js
var array = [{ source: 'A', target : 'C', value: 25 }, { source: 'E', target: 'F', value: 5}, { source: 'C', target: 'A', value: 20 }],
    hash = {},
    pairs = array.reduce((r, { source, target, value }) => {
        var key = [source, target].sort().join('|');
        if (!hash[key]) {
            r.push(hash[key] = { source, target, value });
            return r;
        }
        hash[key].value += value;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(pairs);
```

Answer (score 2):

First generate all possible pairs using two for loops, then iterate over each pari using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to check if the source/target properties match, if so, compute the sum:

```js
const arr = [
  {source: 'A', target : 'C', value: 25}, 
  {source: 'E', target: 'F', value: 5}, 
  {source: 'C', target: 'A', value: 20}
];

const pairs = arr => {
  const out = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
    for (let j = i; j < arr.length - 1; ++j) {
      out.push([arr[i], arr[j + 1]]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

pairs(arr).forEach(pair => {
  if (pair[0].source === pair[1].target && pair[0].target === pair[1].source) {
    console.log(pair[0].value + pair[1].value);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```js
var abc = [
{source: 'A', target : 'C', value: 25}, 
{source: 'E', target: 'F', value: 5}, 
{source: 'C', target: 'A', value: 20},
{source: 'C', target: 'A', value: 200} //To test all pairs
]


//Here you can use for loop to get pairs of each record
var sourceA = abc[0].source;
var targetA = abc[0].target;

//check source against target and vice versa
var result = abc.filter(x => x.target == sourceA && x.source == targetA);
console.log("Result");
console.log(result);

//if you want sum then
var totalAmount = 0;
result.forEach( data => totalAmount = totalAmount + data.value);
console.log("Total amount");
console.log(totalAmount);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're looking for all the pairs, you can use:

```
var arr = [
  {source: 'A', target : 'C', value: 25}, 
  {source: 'E', target: 'F', value: 5}, 
  {source: 'C', target: 'A', value: 20},
  {source: 'D', target: 'A', value: 2},
  {source: 'A', target: 'D', value: 1}
]    

var res = arr.reduce((acc, {source,target,value}, id, input) => {
    var findPair = el => el.source == target && el.target == source;
    var pair = !acc.some(findPair) && input.find(findPair);
    return pair ? [...acc, {source, target, sum: pair.value + value}]: acc;
}, []);
```

This returns:

```
[ { source: 'A', target: 'C', sum: 45 },
  { source: 'D', target: 'A', sum: 3 } ]
```